# Good tutorials on code management?

Tags: version-control

I have been coding since a long time but I have never ever used the code management systems like CVS or SVN.

Can you please suggest any guides which start from basics and then go with the concepts of the individual software and their intricacies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eric Sink's [Source Control HOWTO](http://www.ericsink.com/scm/source_control.html) is a nice (non tool-specific) introduction, although I don't know if it's up-to-date with the latest [DVCSs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_revision_control).

Answer (score 1):

Have you read the SVN book?

http://svnbook.red-bean.com/

Answer (score 0):

A really basic one for the really good [darcs](http://darcs.net) can be found [here](http://wiki.darcs.net/DarcsWiki/GettingStarted).

You should be ready in under 20 minutes!

Having done the little tutorial above, see the [links to further documentation](http://wiki.darcs.net/DarcsWiki). If you understood the concept, nearly every darcs command can be found in the [darcs cheat sheet](http://parmenioon.free.fr/darcs-cheat-sheet.pdf) (only one page!).

It may look like darcs was a really basic version control system but in fact it supports unique features none of the other VCS (I know) have (e.g. patch cherry picking without loosing the patches identity).

Answer (score 0):

I would start off with reading the Wikipedia articles on the two

CVS can be found [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concurrent_Versions_System)

Subversion can be found [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subversion_(software))

Then for more detail about Subversion you can look at the red book [here](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/).

I don't know of an equivalent for CVS.

Finally for an overview of version control you can start at Wikipedia [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revision_control).

Answer (score 0):

My favorite document on the subject remains [High-level Best Practices
in Software Configuration Management](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/bestpractices.html). This is an excellent white paper that I still use as reference whenever I need to introduce colleagues to good SCM practices. Here is the abstract:

> When deploying new SCM (software configuration management) tools, implementers sometimes focus on perfecting fine-grained activities, while unwittingly carrying forward poor, large-scale practices from their previous jobs or previous tools. The result is a well-executed blunder. This paper promotes some high-level best practices that reflect the authors' experiences in deploying SCM.